# Centos 7 - where is jfx library for openjdk8?

Tags: java, linux, javafx, centos, centos7

I have centos 7.1. And I installed openjdk8 and openjdk-devel8. However, when I tried to compile in netbeans my jfx application I get package javafx.* does not exist. After some investigation I see that there is no jfxrt.jar in jdk. Besides

```
[root@localhost ext]# yum provides jfxrt.jar
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.astpage.ru
 * epel: epel.besthosting.ua
 * extras: mirror.astpage.ru
 * nux-dextop: mirror.li.nux.ro
 * updates: mirror.astpage.ru
adobe-linux-x86_64/filelists             |  619 B  00:00:00     
base/7/x86_64/filelists_db               | 6.0 MB  00:00:01     
epel/x86_64/filelists_db                 | 6.3 MB  00:00:01     
extras/7/x86_64/filelists_db             |  87 kB  00:00:00     
nux-dextop/x86_64/filelists_db           | 2.3 MB  00:00:02     
updates/7/x86_64/filelists_db            | 836 kB  00:00:00     
No matches found
[root@localhost ext]#
```

So my question - how to add jfx library to openjdk 8 on centos 7?

Comment: This is better asked at http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: As I understand it, you need to build JavaFX independently; it is not included as part of OpenJDK. There are some instructions for building OpenJFX [here](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Building+OpenJFX)

Comment: @James_D I think you are right - at least I found no rpm and finally built it myself