# JavaFX error while accessing SAP GUI on centOS

Tags: java, linux, sap-gui

I have installed SAP GUI 7.40 for linux on client computer including JRE 1.8.0.04 but when I try to access the GUI it gives error:

> The system requirement are not meet. Your Java Virtual machine does not support javafx required to run the SAP GUI for Java 7.40 rev 4.

My client OS is CentOS. I event changed `JAVA_HOME` path in `/etc/profile`, but its still giving the same error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Oracle Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) rather than the OpenJDK based version which ships with CentOS.  Unfortunately, the Java versions which ship with CentOS don't include JavaFX at the moment.

See also:

- [Centos 7 - where is jfx library for openjdk8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011339/centos-7-where-is-jfx-library-for-openjdk8) - and related: [unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/200093/centos-7-where-is-jfx-library-for-openjdk8) version of the same question.